# Nov 22 Google analytics spam traffic

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

Is it possible to create a analytics filter with multiple conditions?

Recently I started seeing a large jump in sessions and page views on my site.

I was able to lock this traffic down by a number of critera

- Browser: chrome
- Browser version: 97.0.4692.71
- Operating system: Linux
- Screen resolution: 1440x900

[image]

I had no issue creating a custom segment with the exclusion rules as shown in the above image, but you can't edit the `All users` segment.

I was hoping to be able to add the same conditions to a filter that I can apply to all of my properties, but it seems that filters don't include and/or rule conditioning.

Is there anyway I can block this sessions/hits matching these criteria that I can apply to all my universal analytics and GA4 properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not in GA4. GA4 is still seriously inferior even comparing to UA.

You can do it before GA4, in GTM for future cases.
Or you can do it after GA4, in BQ.

But if it's real analytics spam, they would be bypassing GTM. Therefore, only BQ or wherever you ETL the data to after GA4.